# Convolutional Neural Network autoencoder with ASCII code pixel

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, ascii, pixel, autoencoder

I have a question about Convolutional Neural Network Autoencoder. I saw lot's of tutorials about it and the input was images. I was wondering if it is possible to use as input to use files whose pixels are represented by Ascii codes in .txt format ?

For example, a .txt file as this structure:

```
0 0 1.875223e+01
1 0 1.875223e+01
2 0 2.637685e+01
...
```

If anyone has a Python example with an autoencoder with ASCII file as input, I will appreciate.
I am still in the reflexion if it is better to use ASCII files as input or directly image files. what do you think?

Comment: I can't see what those three lines of sample data are supposed to mean. please clarify. -- whatever you're trying to do... read the data, convert to something sensible, and use it?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, the goal is to inject these ASCII file into a CNN autoencoder and decode the output.

Comment: that's the goal but what's the problem with that? please review [ask]